# Difference in writing a code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

What difference does it make if you write a code inside UIViewController as compared to writing inside viewDidLoad? I tried posting the same code in the both the spaces out of curiosity anything in anything. Does it make any major difference otherwise?

Comment: This question would be much easier to understand if you showed code samples.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is a method where you can write any code you want. `UIViewController` is a class developed by Apple and you should not modify anything in there

Comment: What do you mean? `viewDidLoad` is a method of `UIViewController` class

Comment: First understand life cycle of application - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also really don't get your intention. However, viewDidLoad is called exactly once, when the controller is first loaded into memory. That's the point where you usually want to instantiate any instance variables and build any views that live for the entire lifecycle of this view controller. Nevertheless, usually the view isn't visible at this point.

Then you have also other functions such as viewDidAppear, which is called when the view is actually visible. This method could be called a couple of time during the lifecycle.

But you can also read through the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html), which are very useful sometimes.

Comment: Does this answer make sense with OP's question. BTW do you understand what OP is asking for?

Comment: I told him what happens if he writes a code within viewDidLoad. Most likely he wants to know the difference in writing code without viewDidLoad of a custom ViewController and in writing it just within the class!? So yes, from my point of view it does make sense, since know he knows the purpose of viewDidLoad and thus the difference to writing it just within the class scope in another function or to declaring a variable. That's then like always in swift! Don't see your problem....

Comment: Thanks guys, I am really new to programming, so it might be a stupid question for you pro's. :)